# Heroku not detecting Procfile in resources tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, discord.py

I am building a python discord bot with discord.py

I made the Procfile with `echo>Procfile`

I put `worker: python bot.py`

I edited the file with notepad++

When I went to the resources page, it didn't show the Procfile in Dnos

Comment: how are deploying on Heroku using GitHub or anything else?

Comment: I tried using both heroku git cli and github

Comment: write this in the procfile :- web: gunicorn bot:main and place it in the same repository and try again 'bot' is the name of your python file

Comment: Assuming that the default Python runtime for Heroku is Python3, otherwise consider specifying python3. Also workers don't immediately show up after deploy you'll have to refresh the page.